# give random order to $http json oject through angular JS controller

Tags: json, angularjs

I pull in a JSON object with my controller below, but how do I make the order random, on each page refresh?

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'makeRandom', function ($scope, $http, makeRandom) {
$http.get('projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {
  $scope.works = data; 
   });
 makeRandom.forEach($scope.works, function(work) {
  work.rank = Math.random();
  });    
}]);
```

**template.html**

```
 <section ng-repeat="work in works | orderBy:'rank'" class="showcase {{work.class}}">
  ...
</section>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array

Comment: not sure, as the problem i have is getting data from a Http request and randomizing that data for each scope inside a ng-repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much have all the work done, you just need to put it together:

This is based off your work:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

  $http.get('projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.works = data; 
  }).error(function(){

    // works on error response because I don't have your code, just copy this to success response
    // here I just generate a list of ids and then randomize them
    var works = [];
    for(var i=0; i< 20; i++){
      works.push({id: i});
    }
    $scope.works = makeRandom(works);
  });

  function makeRandom(inputArray){
    angular.forEach(inputArray, function(value){
      value.rank = Math.random();
    });
    return inputArray; 
  }

}]);
```

HTML:

```
<section ng-repeat="work in works | orderBy:'rank'" class="showcase {{work.class}}">
    {{work.rank}} {{work}} 
</section>
```

Here is a working example: http://plnkr.co/edit/xIwD0zWdodnYSIupm1va?p=preview

Comment: Thanks SoluableNonagon. I'd like to loop on the works.length, but then doesn't work.

`app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('projects/projects.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.works = data; 
    }).success(function(){

    var works = [];
    for(var i=0; i< this.length; i++){
      works.push({id: i});
    }
    $scope.works = makeRandom(works);
  });

  function makeRandom(inputArray){
    angular.forEach(inputArray, function(value){
      value.rank = Math.random();
    });
    return inputArray; 
  }

}]);`

Comment: ** HTML**
`<section ng-repeat="work in works | orderBy:'rank'" class="showcase {{work.class}}">
    <a ng-href="#/work/:id">
      <hgroup>
      <h4>{{work.title}}</h4>
      <p>{{work.sub}}</p>
      </hgroup>
    </a>
  </section>`

Comment: hey @cheers_to_you , can you put together a plunker (just fork the link above) and replicate the issue you're having?

Comment: g'day @SoluableNonagon, here's my plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/pk7Jp4Obk4YJwvhTgRop?p=preview) you can see i added `this.length` but the list never refreshes as a random list, its always in the same order.  Really appreciate your expert help. Thanks.

Comment: any ideas on finding the length of my array and returning that for the works.data? @SoluableNonagon